# Constraints.mustValidateIn in a StateMachine

Tags: slottime, statemachines

I have an issue with `Constraints.mustValidateIn` in a StateMachine.
In the case using `Interval.to deadline` everything works as expected. But in the case: `Interval.from deadline` the constraint is never valid.
I also tried to build the interval by hand to exclude issues with closure: `Interval {ivFrom = LowerBound (Finite $ deadline object) False, ivTo = UpperBound PosInf True}` Tried with and without closure but it does not have any effect. Also waiting and use the transition in a slot which is far beyond the deadline does not work.

Docs say :

```
 mustValidateIn :: forall i o. POSIXTimeRange -> TxConstraints i o

 *mustValidateIn r requires the transaction's time range to be contained in r.*
```

If I understand it correct, in this case it means the transaction have to happen between deadline and infinity, which should be represented by the interval above?

I define the deadline in the trace as : `slotToEndPOSIXTime def 25`

Very confusing is: when I change it to `slotToBeginPOSIXTime def 25` without changing anything else the behavior turns around...
Anyway my waitForNSlots in the trace are always minimum 3 slots so it should also not run in some limit case.
The actual distance between `slotToBeginPOSIXTime` and `slotToEndPOSIXTime` is, if calculated in repl, 999 milliseconds as I would expect with a slot time of 1s.

(Also tried to add / subtract some seconds from the POSIXTime, which had no effect)

Do am I miss something here?

Thank you for support

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Slots are 1 second and cannot be broken down any further. So when you use the `slotToEndPOSIXTime def 25`, you will get something like 1596059104999. This number is number is in milliseconds, and is not a valid slot because of the trailing 999. You need to add 1 to this number to bump it up to 1596059105000 so that it is evenly divisible by 1000(1000ms/1Second).

I hope that helps!