# Why does the grab function in the vesting contract need two slots to complete?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

This is about Week3/Homework1 of the third Plutus-Pioneer-Program.

Why does the grab endpoint need two slots to resolve and release the funds back to the wallet1?

1. This will not create a transaction
   [image: Wait for 1 slot after the grab endpoint was called]
2. This will create the transaction

[image: Wait for 2 slots after the grab endpoint was called]

[Code to the contract](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week03/src/Week03/Homework1.hs)

Comment: A hunch: maybe because of Constraints.mustValidateIn? Try changing/removing that and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because 1 slot is not enough to meet the interval when using `Constraints.mustValidateIn`.

Check this post for more information on why that happens: [Constraints.mustValidateIn in a StateMachine](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/3672/constraints-mustvalidatein-in-a-statemachine)